# How to disable Hybrid Shutdown in Windows with a Command Line

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, registry, autohotkey

How to disable Hybrid Shutdown in Windows with a Command Line.

I am using a ramdisk (with imdisk software), after the upgrade from Windows 8.1 pro into Windows 10 pro - The Computer does Save automatic My Ramdisk to My Hard Disk everytime if i Shutdown my Windows, **i do not want that**. (The ramdisk Size is to Big [2GB] and i want to use it with a clean ramdisk).

Is it Maybe possible that i have Two **msdos** commanding scripts On my Desktop.(Other Languages like **autohotkey** or **Python** is for me also ok.)

The Scripts must can do this.

```
1 - Disable Hybrid and then Shutdown Windows.

2 - Enable Hybrid and then Shutdown Windows.
```

Comment: If you expect a script written to your specifications you may be in for a long wait. You write the code, we try to help you with any associated problems.

Comment: No it is not possible with two msdos scripts as you are not running MS-DOS.

Comment: This should probably help: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html#option2

Comment: Apparently you can just use the `SHUTDOWN` command in a batch file to control the full shutdown versus a hybrid shutdown. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7418-shut-down-computer-windows-10-a.html#option8  Gooogle is amazing.

Comment: I think the question is valid. Op is asking for one command (in a script file). And not to be spoon fed some extensive script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these msdos bat files:

1 - HybridOn_ShutDown.bat

This will save the Whole Ram memory to your HardDisk (MemoryFile), 
and then it will ShutDown Windows. The next time that you will start up your Computer, it Will Load your (MemoryFile) into the Ram Memory - The Pros are:The Computer will Startup Faster and it will remember all your data + Including the Ramdisk data.

```
@echo off
powercfg /h on
shutdown /h
```

2 - HybridOff_ShutDown.bat

This Will Shutdown Windows Without Saving The Ram Memory to your HardDisk. The next time that you will start up your Computer, it will do a Clean/Fresh Windows Start up + With a Clean/Fresh Ramdisk Start up.

```
@echo off
powercfg /h off
shutdown /p /f
```

note - This works only if you run the bat files (**as administrator**)

And If you want to run it direct you can use:

Method 2: Converting the .BAT files into .EXE files with Admin Manifest added.

[Click Here](https://www.techgainer.com/create-batch-file-automatically-run-administrator/) and Read Method 2:

Answer (score 0):

To disable Hybrid Shutdown (a.k.a Fast Startup) feature from command line, or by a script/macro, 
in a .bat file use:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F
```

or using PowerShell .ps1 file:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" -Name HiberbootEnabled -Value 0
```

To enable it again, replace 0 by 1:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F
```

or using PowerShell .ps1 file:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" -Name HiberbootEnabled -Value 1
```

Elevated access is required.
This is the setting which will be affected by above commands:

[image: Enable-Disable Hybrid Shutdown]

I didn't include `shutdown` command in these examples, because it shouldn't be necessary to use them together like that. 
Actually in your case, if you just want an icon on a Desktop to Shutdown completely when desired,
- Keep Hybrid Shutdown ON
- create an Icon (a bat file) with just `shutdown /p` inside
Then when you want to do a Hybrid Shutdown, do it from Windows menu,
and when you want "old-school" shutdown, which discards RAM contents, click on the Icon.
shutdown /p doesn't need Admin rights - elevated access.

If you still also want the second Icon - command for the Hybrid Shutdown is:
`shutdown /s /t 0 /hybrid`
This would have the same effect as using Windows menu's Shut Down.
This command only works if you have Hybrid Shut Down enabled by means described above.

Another option, which I wouldn't really recommend, is to do a Restart and wait for the moment when your PC power-cycles and turn it off by a Power Button on that exact instant.

---

#### In a reaction to `G. user17`'s answer:

adding /f for `force` will perform disgraceful shutdown, where windows will not ask to save unsaved files and forcibly closes programs which are awaiting user's reaction or are ignoring closing command from system. This might be because they want to perform some closing steps, like removing temp files, saving config, etc.

shutdown /h does a Hibernate, not Hybrid Shut Down
Hybrid Shut Down is Logoff + Hibernate and is perceived by user as a Shutdown.

Turning Hibernation OFF using command `powercfg /h off` will disable Hibernation all together. As Hybrid Shutdown is a feature dependent on Hibernation, it will also be disabled. But if you want to turn off Hybrid Shut Down only and keep Hibernate option enabled, use the steps described above.

There also is an opposite option, to keep Hybrid Shut Down but disable Hibernate. This would spare disk space as hiberfile will be smaller.
`POWERCFG /HIBERNATE /TYPE REDUCED`